# Labels not updated inside jQuery dialog fired by asyncpostbacktrigger

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

What i have is.

**In my .aspx file:**

This is the update panel with the button used to open the dialog.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" RenderMode="Inline">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <%--(A GridView)--%>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="BtnReport_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Outside the update there is the div of the dialog.

```
<div class="dialog-report" style="font-size: medium;">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="LblReport" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtBox_Report" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the configuration of the dialog i did:

```
$(".dialog-report").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    title: "Sala de Comando",
    height: 400,
    width: 300,
    autoOpen: false,
    appendTo: "form"
});
```

**In the C# codebehind:**

```
protected void BtnReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.UpdatePanel,GetType(), "open-dialog", "$('.dialog-report').dialog('open');", true);
    LblReport.Text = "some text";
}
```

Actualy the dialog opens but dont do nothing about the label, it shows nothing in the place of the label. When it would have the text "some text".
Any help, tks in advance.

**If i use the asp:postback the label gets the text if i use the asp:asyncpostback it doesn't**

Answer (score 0):

A part from all the errors in your snippet that won't allow even compile or will give you a ysod... Where did you find `.dialog('open')`? Just typing `open` somewhere will not make it happen.

Remove that and the modal will open.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.UpdatePanel, GetType(), "open-dialog", "$('.dialog-report').dialog();", true);
```

Comment: the problem is that the label dont get updated. The button click is doing the Scriptmanager code but also in the button click there's an update on the label.text that dont happen.Tks for replying.

Comment: `LblReport` and `LblRreport`. Spot the difference. So either there are 2 labels with those names, or your project cannot even compile/run!

Comment: the snippet doesn't work probably because of (A Gridview)

Comment: the id label is the same it was typing error and the code is running just happening can't update de label text with asyncpostback. tks for replying.

Comment: the buttonclick was wrong also the name of the dialog really sorry for the typing errors. I am using this as replication of the original code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using inside the dialog div an new update panel(UpdatePanel1).

And in codebehind added `UpdatePanel1.Update();`